# Add invisible button to a span in html

Tags: html

I have the following code:

```
<div class="top-item">
    <i class="fa fa-history"> </i> 
    <span class="history item"> History</span>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
</div>
```

What I want to obtain is when I click on the text, History, to behave like a button is clicked. I did it but only with the button also visible in the area, like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQHdX.png).

How can I get rid of the button but keep its functionality?

Comment: `<span class="history item" onclick="myFunction()"> History</span>` Why not just attach event handler with `<SPAN>`?

Comment: be careful, onclick doesn't run in all browsers. perhaps it's better to bind the function via javascript

Comment: The best thing to do here would be to _keep_ the button (accessibility!), and simply _format_ it to look like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can updated your HTML with following

```
<div class="top-item">
    <i class="fa fa-history"> </i> 
    <span class="history item" onclick="myFunction()"> History</span>
</div>
```

or add following CSS for this

```css
.top-item button {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-item">
    <i class="fa fa-history"> </i> 
    <span class="history item"> History</span>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
</div>
```

or you can use `display: none`

```css
.top-item button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-item">
    <i class="fa fa-history"> </i> 
    <span class="history item"> History</span>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but i think playing with position absolute is very bad practice in this case

Comment: @mtizziani that's why i suggest three different options, which one OP like, OP can use..

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combo of js and css to achieve this:

css

```
.hidden {display: none}
```

js/jQuery

```
$('.history').on('click', function()
{
    //do some stuff
})
```

then you wouldn't need a hidden button - just a script :)

also don't do inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a click action on your button, based on another action you can use jQuery

```
$('.history').on('click', function() {
    $('.top-item button').trigger('click');
});
```